# Extracting stored data from dictionary VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dictionary that I've populated with information that I've extracted from a master table with roughly 65 000 unique rows. I would then like to filter through the dictionary and only extract the items if they contain a certain value. Below is my code for creating the dictionary from the initial data, which I've borrowed heavily from other methods I found online :

```
Sub dict_extract()

    Dim cell    As Range
    Dim Data    As Variant
    Dim Dict    As Object
    Dim Item    As Variant
    Dim Key     As Variant
    Dim rng     As Range
    Dim RngBeg  As Range
    Dim RngEnd  As Range
    Dim Wks     As Worksheet
    Dim x       As Long
    Dim y       As Long
    Dim i As Long


'Speed Up
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

        Set Wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FullCarriers")

        Set RngBeg = Wks.Range("A2:G2")
        Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, RngBeg.Column).End(xlUp)

        If RngEnd.Row < RngBeg.Row Then Exit Sub

        Set rng = Wks.Range(RngBeg, RngEnd)

        Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare



            For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
                Key = Trim(cell)
                Item = cell.Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count).Value

                If Not Dict.Exists(Key) Then
                    Dict.Add Key, Item
                Else
                    ' To increase the rows in the 2-D array it must first be transposed.
                    ' Only the last dimension of an array can be resized.
                    Data = Application.Transpose(Dict(Key))
                        x = UBound(Data, 1)
                        y = UBound(Data, 2) + 1
                        ReDim Preserve Data(1 To x, 1 To y)
                    ' Transposing the array a second time restores the original order.
                    Data = Application.Transpose(Data)

                    ' Load the new data.
                    For x = 1 To UBound(Item, 2)
                        Data(y, x) = Item(1, x)
                    Next x

                    ' Save the Data.
                    Dict(Key) = Data
                End If
            Next cell
```

Now, when I go to print the items in the dictionary to my worksheets, I have these lines:

```
        For i = 2 To 14

            Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Level " & i).Range("A2")

            For Each Item In Dict.items
                x = UBound(Item, 1)
                y = UBound(Item, 2)
                rng.Resize(x, y).Value = Item
                Set rng = rng.Offset(x, 0)
            Next Item

        Next i
```

What I'd like to do is as I'm looping through my dictionary items, see if they contain a certain character and print to my worksheet if they contain that character, and do nothing if they don't. The "code" I need to filter is something like:

```
If Mid(Item,13,2) = Format(i, "00") Then
{Print to Worksheet i}
Else
{Do Nothing}
```

Only problem is I have no idea how to accomplish this. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: `Item` is an array, so which part of it do you want to look at before adding it to the sheet?

Comment: Why use a dictionary ? Could you just scan down the master table once and write the row to a specific sheet if column 1 contains the pattern you are looking for ?

Comment: I could CDP1802, however the master table is 65 000 rows by 7 or 8 columns, and per each "i" value I would need to write around 4000 to 5000 rows to other worksheets

Comment: You have to write to other worksheets using the dictionary. How may "i" values are there and can you give some examples ?

Comment: 14 i values. The first column of the table is what I need to parse. If I find the correct i value, then copy that whole table row over to the corresponding worksheet. The string in column 1 that I need to parse takes he following form: F_LTC91-ABS-01-xx-yy ; i = 1, formatted to "01". Other strings may look like: F_LTC91-ABS-i-xx-yy, where i = 01 to 14

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you only want the values in colums A to G copied to the Level sheets. This processes 100,000 rows in about 5 seconds. It uses 2 14 element arrays to hold the target sheet and target row for each i value.

```
Option Explicit
Sub process()

    Const IVALUES As Integer = 14
    Const SRC = "FullCarriers"

    Dim t0 As Single, t1 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, iRow As Long, iRowLast As Long
    Dim iID As Integer, sID As String

    ' set row counter for each sheet
    Dim iRowTarget(IVALUES) As Long
    Dim wsTarget(IVALUES) As Worksheet, rngTarget As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For i = 1 To IVALUES
        Set wsTarget(i) = wb.Sheets("Level " & i) ' sheet name
        iRowTarget(i) = 1
    Next

    ' clear cheets
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "Level?#" Then
            ws.Cells.Clear
            'Debug.Print ws.Name
        End If
    Next

    ' scan the source data sheet
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SRC)
    iRowLast = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' start at row 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ws
    For iRow = 2 To iRowLast

        sID = Mid(.Cells(iRow, 1), 13, 2)
        If sID Like "##" And sID <= IVALUES Then

            iID = CInt(sID)
            ' copy cola A to G
            Set rngTarget = wsTarget(iID).Range("A" & iRowTarget(iID) & ":G" & iRowTarget(iID))
            rngTarget.Value = .Range("A" & iRow & ":G" & iRow).Value
            iRowTarget(iID) = iRowTarget(iID) + 1

        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect pattern " & sID & " at Row " & iRow
        End If

    Next
    End With
    t1 = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Finished at Row " & iRow

    MsgBox iRowLast & " rows scanned ", vbInformation, "Finished in " & Int(t1 - t0) & " seconds"

End Sub
```

These scripts I used to generate test data

```
Sub testdata()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsAdd As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("FullCarriers")
    ws.Cells.Clear

    ' create 14 sheets
    ' n = wb.Sheets.Count
    ' For i = 0 To 13
    '  Set wsAdd = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(n + i))
    '  wsAdd.Name = "Level " & i + 1
    ' Next

    Dim s As String, sID As String, sNo As String
    For i = 2 To 100001
        sID = Format(Int(1 + Rnd() * 14), "00")
        sNo = Format(Int(1 + Rnd() * 99), "00")
        ' example F_LTC91-ABS-01-xx-yy
        s = rndStr(1) & "_" & rndStr(3) & sNo & "-" & rndStr(3) & "-" & sID & _
        "-" & rndStr(2) & "-" & rndStr(2)
        ws.Cells(i, 1) = s
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = "Row " & i & " Col B"
        ws.Cells(i, 3) = sID
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = "Row " & i & " Col G"
    Next

End Sub

Function rndStr(ByVal n As Integer) As String
   Dim i As Integer
   For i = 1 To n
     rndStr = rndStr & Chr(Rnd() * 25 + 65)
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: Wow thanks CDP1802. I will try implementing this into my workbook and see the results

Comment: I'm getting an error while running the process."Object variable or With block variable not set". Run-time error '91' on the "Set rngTarget" line

Comment: @CarriersMan I managed to get that error by having 00  as the I value. After the line sID = Mid(.Cells(iRow, 1), 13, 2) add debug.print iRow,sID and look in the immediate window for what the last line is when it crashes. Check that row in your data.

Comment: It actually seems to crash when i = "01". I'll continue searching as to why

Comment: I think it actually has something to do with sID = 01. If I modify your test data script to only have sIDs from 02 to 14 then the program runs fine

Comment: T_QGO46-MLB-01-WT-JN . Just an example, it fails regardless of what the other strings are, it seems that the main string that's important is the "01". If I change it to "05" then it works

Comment: Yes the for loop is after the set wb, also my i = 2 is in that for loop, instead of i = 1 as you mention

Comment: @carriers That's why the 01's don't work because you have started at 2. That loop sets the target sheet for the I values.